# Using functions with the same name from different classes; what pattern is this?

Tags: c++, oop

I would like to know what OOP technique this is so that I can gain a better understanding of how to use it, and what is does in a wider range of applications.

I have seen this technique used in a few programs. Yet I have tried researching it and I have not found any article anywhere that even makes mention of it.

in fileA.cpp when I have this member function of class A

```
   // an object of class B is instantiated in class B
   classB _classB

   void signup(int n){
        _classB.signup(n);
        // rest of the function
   };
```

then in fileB we have this member function of class B

```
   void signup(int n){
        // rest of function
   };
```

Is there definition for this technique where a function of a particular name calls a function of similar name from another class. Is there any articles I can read about this, so that I can further use it in my programming?

Comment: I think you narrowed down your problem too much. There are several things that rely on functions having the same name or signature, including polymorphism, overloading and several different design patterns. Having same function names is not a goal, it's a way to achieve some other goal.

Comment: There is a technique called overloading functions, but I don't think that's what's happening here.

Comment: class B inherits class A or the reverse ? The tag C must be removed, you speak about classes

Comment: Encapsulation, at best.  The function names are not relevant.

Comment: If you were in Python, I would call this duck typing. If you're being particularly clever with templates, you could probably still call this duck typing. But with only the information you've given us, there's no relation between the two functions at all.

Comment: It's not an OOP technique, really. You could call it a facade, or a proxy, or a few other patterns depending on _why_ you're doing this, but there's nothing really OO-specific about it.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Is it "typing", though, really?

Comment: You might call it the ”coincidence” pattern, or the ”this name makes sense both here and there” pattern. That is, the naming is not a ”technique”, and it doesn’t have a name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any particular name for what you're doing, because it's not a pattern nor anything really particularly special/magical.

That being said, in colloquial discussions I might say that these functions "forward" to the other functions. If I'm "forwarding" in this manner I'll usually have the same function names, because they do the same things.

But, again, this is *just me*.

Other terms (stolen from the comments section) may include *façade* or *proxy*.

When you start doing things like hiding implementations, or wrapping symbols for transport across ABI boundaries, you might be using techniques like *marshalling* or patterns like *PIMPL*. Again, these terms do not describe your function names at all, but you'll almost certainly find a degree of function name re-use when employing such techniques/patterns.

Comment: i think that forwarding to other functions is the best way of describing what is taking place in the above code